# How is "accepting a bet with gain proportional to X-P(X)" to be interpreted? (de Finetti's subjective probability)

Tags: probability

In Theory of Probability, de Finetti states that the (subjective) probability $\bar{x}$ you evaluate for $P(X)$ must be such that you accept any bet with gains proportional to $X-\bar{x}$, i.e. gains $Y = c(X-\bar{x})$ for any c, positive or negative.

I've been trying to rack my brain but not figured out in what sense he means this. What kind of bet are we talking about? My opponent pays me $c$ and if $X$ occurs, I pay back $Y$? Or my opponent pays me $Y$ if the event does not occur, and I pay my opponent $Y$ if it does? Or something else altogether?

The perhaps useful follow-up is that if I suggest incoherent probabilities, my opponent can build a linear combination of these bets (which I must accept) that guarantees a loss on my end. I'm familiar with the "Dutch book" argument, but I just can't slot in what I know with the phrasing "bet with gains proportional to $X-\bar{x}$".

If we imagine a coin (X=0 or X=1), and I suspect that $\bar{x} = 0.6$, how exactly would the bet play out?

And, if the case of the coin turns out to be too easy -- how does this generalise to dice? (Where my payoff X is 1..6, and an inexploitable $\bar{x}=3.5$, and e.g. 3 would be exploitable through this adversarial betting situation.

Edit: I should say for completeness that I do understand the idea that my probability of an event can be converted to the odds that I'm offering either side of a bet at. I still don't understand how that relates to $X-\bar{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sense in which this bet is meant is actually described later in the book: For an event E, my opponent pays me $c$ if the event occurs, and I pay my opponent $c\hat{p}$ If the event does not occur. This follows quite naturally, actually, from the expression $c(E - \hat{p})$. I'm not sure why I didn't see it.

So for a fair coin, if I assign $\hat{p} = 0.5$, I have to accept a bet where I get paid 10 if the coin comes up heads, and I lose 5 if it comes up tails, for an expected gain of 5.

If I instead would erroneously assign $\hat{p} = 0.6$ I would still get 10  for heads, but have to cough up 6 for tails, for an expected gain of 4. If I assigned $\hat{p} = 0.4$, my opponent would take the other side of the bet (set $c = -10$ instead of 10) and I would gain only 4 again. (My opponent, then, gets the other 6.)

Extending to the case of the die, we would then have $c(X - \bar{x})$: we have to pay our opponent $c\bar{x}$, and then for any X that comes up, we get paid $cX$.

So the following cases are, in the case of a fair die and $c=1$, equally likely.

- Side 1: we pay our opponent 3.5, and we get paid 1, for a loss of 2.5.
- Side 2: we pay our opponent 3.5, and we get paid 2, for a loss of 1.5.
- ...
- Side 6: we pay our opponent 3.5, and we get paid 6, for a gain of 2.5.

Do this enough times and we have gained 0, but also lost 0, making it a fair bet.

If we suggest some other $\bar{x}$, like 3, our opponent would probably pick some negative $c$ like -1, and the cases would instead be

- Side 1: our opponent pays us 3, and we pay our opponent 1, for a gain of 2.
- Side 2: our opponent pays us 3, and we pay our opponent 2, for a gain of 1.
- Side 3: ..., gain of 0.
- Side 4: ..., loss of 1.
- Side 5: ..., loss of 2.
- Side 6: our opponent pays us 3, and we pay our opponent 6, for a loss of 3.

This is in total a loss of 3, instead, making $\bar{x}$ a bad choice for the prevision of a fair die.